# Issue obtaining minimum value of list/array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, minimum

I'm having a weird issue, at least I can't explain the reason for this behaviour.

I generate a list of random values with the function `rand_data` as defined below. When I attempt to extract the minimum value using the `min()` function, it returns the whole list, which leads me to believe it is not a list but an *array*.

But if I attempt to use the `.min()` attribute it returns the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'min'
```

What is happening here? Is `x1` a list or an array?

Minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np

def rand_data():
    return np.random.uniform(low=10., high=20., size=(10,))

# Generate data.
x1 = [rand_data() for i in range(1)]

print min(x1)
print x1.min()
```

Comment: an array is a list in python

Comment: You have a *list* object, containing the results of 1 `rand_data()` call.

Comment: You're generating a list with one element in it and that element is an array

Comment: @GoBrewers14 ohh that's an easy explanation. Would you mind posting it as an answer?

Comment: Nevermind, I see @MartijnPieters just posted that exact answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used a list comprehension:

```
x1 = [rand_data() for i in range(1)]
```

You now have a Python list object containing **one** result from `rand_data()`.

Since `rand_data()` uses [`numpy.random.uniform()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) that means you have a list *containing* a numpy array.

Don't use a list comprehension here, it is clearly not what you wanted:

```
x1 = rand_data()
```

Comment: I get it now. I was using that method to generate several lists of random data, hence the `[rand_data() for i in range(1)]`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def rand_data(num_elements):
# numpy returns always an array with a defined number
# of elements specified by the size parameter
     return np.random.uniform(low=10., high=20., size=num_elements)

#rand_data will automatically generate the random data for you
# simply specifying the number of elements to generate
x1 = rand_data(10)

print('Minimum value for {0} is {1}'.format(x1, min(x1)))
```